# ADODB Stream: Download Text File Issues

Tags: asp-classic, stream, adodb

I am in a situation where a stream connection is called when the user clicks a download button. When the download button is submitted, a function is called up in ASP, where the download code is executed on the file `BD_Test1.txt`. The contents of this text file are simply `TEST 1`.

The file downloads as normal, however when opening it, all of the HTML code is on the text file.

#### HTML Code

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bulk Download Zipper</title>
    <!--#include file="BD_Download.asp"-->
</head>

<body>
    <center><h1>Bulk Download Zipper</h1></center>

    <br><br>

    <p>Please click "Download" to zip the files.</p>

    <form method="post">
        <br><input type = "submit" name="zipFile" value = "Download"/><br>
    </form>

    <br><br>

    <%
    If (Request.Form("zipFile") <> "") Then
        Call downloadFile()
    End If
    %>
</body>

</html>
```

#### ASP Code

```
<%
Function downloadFile()
    Dim download_File, download_Remove, download_Autoremove

    Set download_File = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    download_File.Type = 1
    download_File.Open
    download_File.LoadFromFile("E:\inetpub\wwwroot\cdc\wnyaccc_erie_niagara_trd-2\youkergav\BulkDownload\resumes\BD_Test1.txt")

    Response.AddHeader "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary" 
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Description", "File Transfer" 
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Resumes.txt"
    Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.BinaryWrite download_File.Read

    download_File.Close
    Set download_File = Nothing
End Function
%>
```

#### Contents of Downloaded Text File

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bulk Download Zipper</title>

</head>

<body>
    <center><h1>Bulk Download Zipper</h1></center>

    <br><br>

    <p>Please click "Download" to zip the files.</p>

    <form method="post">
        <br><input type = "submit" name="zipFile" value = "Download"/><br>
    </form>

    <br><br>

    TEST 1
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the contents of the text file are being inserted where the `downloadFile()` function is called. Is it possible to use a stream connection is this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `downloadFile` function is being called **after** the page has already begun getting served to the client. ASP is simply injecting the result of your function. You will need to override the entire output on POST. Output the html on GET, and output the text file on POST:

```
<%
If (Request.Form("zipFile") <> "") Then
    Call downloadFile()
Else%>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Bulk Download Zipper</title>
        <!--#include file="BD_Download.asp"-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <center><h1>Bulk Download Zipper</h1></center>

        <br><br>

        <p>Please click "Download" to zip the files.</p>

        <form method="post">
            <br><input type = "submit" name="zipFile" value = "Download"/><br>
        </form>

        <br><br>
    </body>

    </html>
<%
End If
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. This makes sense why the downloaded file has the contents that it does. Can you clarify or point me in the right direction as to how one would go about make a "server-side click handler"? Are you referring to using something like AJAX? I'd rather not use a separate file for the `downloadFile` function.

Comment: I don't think ajax is the answer here. But you should have access to your code-behind file. Is there a file with a "cs" or "vb" extension with the same name as your aspx file?

Comment: @MattSpinks If they are using `ADODB.Stream` that's going to be Classic ASP not ASP.Net so it won't have a code behind.

Comment: @GavinYouker, I didn't realize you were using classic ASP. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was going about it the wrong way because I was not thinking about when ASP loads. Thanks for your help.